# Magento2 : How to get last order id in payment module template file

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I am creating a custom payment method module in magento2.

On order place redirecting to to my request controller from script. In request controller I have below code :

```
...
$resultPage = $this->_pageFactory->create();
$resultPage->addHandle('custom_request_index');
return $resultPage;
...
```

In xml file added template file `form.phtml` and it is loading on the page.

All are working but I am trying to get last order id in `form.phtml` file as below :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$checkout_session = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
$incrementId = $checkout_session->getLastRealOrderId();
echo $incrementId;
```

But above code returning nothing. But when I try to log same code in request controller then it returns correct order id.

I have also tried to add a function in block file to get order id in template file like `$block->getLastOrder()` but this function also returning nothing, while other functions in block file working properly.

Why this is happening? How to get last order id in form.phtml file?

Comment: It may be caching issue because block and template has been cached.

Comment: No, I tried to echo some different string every time on form.phtml, and that is showing on page.

Comment: @YogeshKarodiyais right sometimes it creates an issue because of cache but you can also try to `$objectManager->create`  method instead of  `$objectManager->get` method so it fetches new object for you. This is blind shoot

Comment: @YogeshKarodiya, Now changes not reflecting on frontend, I tried `php bin/magento cache:clean`, `php bin/magento cache:flush`, `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`, `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` commands, but still changes not reflecting on frontend. How to remove cache?

Comment: try to get $incrementId into the controller and pass it to the block from controller.

Comment: I'm able to get increment id in controller but How to pass it to block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$checkout_session = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
$order = $checkout_session->getLastRealOrder();
$orderId= $order->getEntityId();
echo $order->getIncrementId();
```

It can help you 
There is a mistake in 2nd line

```
$checkout_session = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
```

Comment: @Piyush, Actually I posted this via cell phone so it was not well arranged

Comment: please check my above comments, now changes in form.phtml also not reflecting on production server.

Comment: i am able to get only the last order id but i need to get all order id